# C# window application checkboxlist selection mode one not working

Tags: c#, desktop-application, checkboxlist

i have window application. now, at run time i am adding one page & checkboxlist inside of that page.

for that my code is:

```
Form inputBox = new Form();

                inputBox.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
                inputBox.ClientSize = size;
                inputBox.Text = "Doc Selection";
                inputBox.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
                inputBox.ControlBox = false;

                System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox DocTypeChkList = new CheckedListBox();
                DocTypeChkList.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 10);
                DocTypeChkList.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
                DocTypeChkList.Items.Add("B");
                DocTypeChkList.Items.Add("P");
                DocTypeChkList.Items.Add("Other");
                DocTypeChkList.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One;
                inputBox.Controls.Add(DocTypeChkList);
```

now, at run time user can check multi check box...i want at a time only one checkbox should be check instead of multi....i already gave selection mode **"ONE"**
 ..

can you let me know.what i am missing????

Thanks

Comment: This is `CheckBoxList` not something like `RadioButtonList`. `SelectionMode` is just for `Select` not for `Check`.

Comment: You should use `radiobuttons`

Comment: `Selection of an item` and `check an item` are two different things. You are selecting it, not checking one item.

Comment: @Shaharyar,  thn for checking..what i have to do?

Answer (score 4):

`CheckedListBox` allows user to check multi-checkboxes and that's the purpose of designing this control. `SelectionMode` is just to indicate that you can select one or more items (an item is considered selected if it's hightlighted not checked). So to work-around you have to add some code to handle the `ItemCheck` event. The mechanism is simple.

```
    int lastCheckedIndex = -1;
    //ItemCheck event handler for your checkedListBox1
    private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Index != lastCheckedIndex)
        {
            if(lastCheckedIndex != -1)
               checkedListBox1.SetItemCheckState(lastCheckedIndex, CheckState.Unchecked);
            lastCheckedIndex = e.Index;
        }
    }
    //To register event
    checkedListBox1.ItemCheck += checkedListBox1_ItemCheck;
```

Comment: i add code for itemcheck event. DocTypeChkList.ItemCheck += System.EventHandler(this.DocTypeChkList_ItemCheck);   it's showing me error

Comment: at runtime how can i add item check event?

Comment: @Kvadiyatar I thought you knew how to register an event handler in c#, see my update to know how.

Comment: @Kvadiyatar where? note that the code above has been tested by me. There is not any chance to throw such a nasty exception here.

Answer (score 2):

In checked list box `SelectionMode.One` means that you can select only one item at a time. but that doesn't mean that you can **check** only one item. Both are different. Feel the difference.

You can't make `CheckedListBox` to use `MultiSelect` also doing so will throw `ArgumentException`

Workaround: Attach ItemCheck event and uncheck all other items

```
checkedListBox1.ItemCheck +=checkedListBox1_ItemCheck;

private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i != e.Index)
        {
            checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: SelectionMode.One means that you can select only one item at a time  ....this is my question...why it's not working...

Comment: Is it your downvote? Read my answer again. this is correct answer. `Selection` is different `Checking` is different!

Comment: `at run time user can check multi check box` Yes user can check multiple items but they can't select Multiple items.

Comment: yes..i read ur answer...my issue is...selection mode is not working & i want to user can check one checkbox at a time...also i gave my code.so, as per that, if you can modify it and answer to me...it's should be helpful for me.

Comment: I didn't vote down. But this is not an answer, it should be a comment

Comment: Am saying the fact man. Does anybody downvote the fact? If you want workaround I'll give you

Comment: @Shaharyar I told the fact and Given workaround too. Now is this fit to be an answer ?

Comment: Now it is an answer. A fact can not be an answer. An answer is the solution of the problem.

Comment: Agree with you @Shaharyar, but When I say the fact I thought OP can realize the truth and if he asks for alternate solution then I can provide workaround!

Comment: @SriramSakthivel & shaharyar ... now, i have one function/method in that i am creating one page dynamic. as per my question code. now, i will write checkedListBox1.ItemCheck +=checkedListBox1_ItemCheck; i will get Itemcheck method/function. but inside of that function i can't declare.  checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, false); bcoz checkedListBox1 should be out of context. try at ur side and let me know.i am looking for the result.

Comment: You mean you need to access `checkedListBox1` where it is not available. If so pass the `checkedListBox` as a parameter to that method